# How to make an equation that contains several matrices?

Tags: equations, matrices

Being new to LaTeX, I find the matrix construction a bit annoying, even for simple matrices. How can I construct the following matrix?

[image]

Comment: The site works best if you say what you tried and what error you got, there does not appear to be anything out of the ordinary there, just `\begin{bmatrix}M_{11}&M_{12}\\M_{21}&M_{22}\end{bmatrix}` repeated a few times with appropriate values in the cells?

Comment: @Mico Considering that someone is spending his time to give me a solution i would be really unpolite to forget to accept an answer.But i cant accept an answer if its not the answer i was looking for.Ofcourse in the case of this specific question David was right that i should post what i have tried till now. :) Btw which is a normal ratio of question/accepted answer ?

Comment: If the answer, or answers, one receives don't provide a workable solution -- I assume that's what you mean by "not the answer I was looking for" -- you should feel free to provide comments on the answers and observe that they don't quite solve your issue; you should probably explain directly what it is you're looking for. If none of the answers are quite OK, and if this happens repeatedly on your queries, it may be that people simply don't understand what it is you need. In such cases, you should probably ask yourself how you might edit your queries to clarify your objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the following is what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright} 
\mleftright % eliminate whitespace inserted by \left and \right
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}M_{11}&M_{12}\\M_{21}&M_{22}\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\begin{bmatrix} \ddot{x}_0 \\ \ddot{\theta} \end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}C_{11}&C_{12}\\C_{21}&C_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ \theta \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```